# Filter out elements if data-attribute matches id of element in another container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

The li items are clickable divs with data-filter attributes. When clicked, I need jQuery to figure out if any of the li items data-filter attributes match with any divs in the "filteringResults" container. Which will then go on to the "filteringResults" container only showing divs which match with any of the selected li items data-filter attributes.

```
<li data-filter='clm, ebusiness, seo'>
  <div class="itemcontainer">
    <img src="site-resources/images/chat-32W.png" alt="">
    <div class="tick"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Engage</p>
</li>
<li data-filter='clm, facebookads, website'>
  <div class="itemcontainer">   
    <img src="site-resources/images/engineering-32W.png" alt="">
    <div class="tick"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Manage</p>
</li>

<ul id="filteringResults">
  <li id="clm">CLM</li>
  <li id="ebusiness">EBusiness</li>
  <li id="seo">SEO</li>
  <li id="website">Webite</li>
  <li id="facebookads">Facebook Ads</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try something first. get stuck then ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector like this

```
$("li").click(function () {
    alert($("[data-filter*=" + this.id + "]").data("filter"));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nFd7C/317/)

Comment: @OllieRussell8 Does this fullfill your need?